# AWS ECR lifecycle policy not removing all untagged images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I am trying to use AWS ECR lifecycle policies to keep my repos clean.

I try to mimic `docker system prune` through a policy of which I hope it cleans up all untagged images, as follows:

- Rule priority: 1
- Rule description: "remove all untagged images"
- Image status: "Untagged"
- Match criteria: ("Image count more than", 1)
- Rule action: *greyed out* ("The only supported value is expire.")

This partially works, partially does not. Within **one repo**, 2 different things happen for the following two sets of images:

- For one set of images (let's call them "A"), it keeps the latest version (as it should), and removes *all* untagged images (images that formerly had the same tag "A", before they got untagged by a newer push)
- For another set of images (let's call them "B"), it keeps the latest version (as it should), but also the most recent untagged version (which it should not), while only removing all *other* untagged images (images that formerly had tag "B", prior to becoming untagged by pushes)

So in the end, I end up with 2 latest images ("A" and "B", as I expected) and one untagged image (the latest overwritten version of "B"), which I expected to be removed.

What am I getting wrong? What's the "lifecycle-policy equivalent" to `docker system prune`, if "delete all untagged, if count of images > 1" does not do the trick?

Comment: As I read your description, with `count > 1` repo B is doing the right thing and repo A isn't. Update your question with the actual life-cycle configuration for both repositories, copied from the CLI.

Comment: Given `count == 1` is the minimum, if that meant that 1 untagged image should remain, how can you set it to "remove all untagged"? The only difference I see is that set "B" (where one untagged image remains undeleted) had a more recent push, but that was already 23 hours ago, so the test run should certainly see that "most recent untagged" image, too.

Comment: That's a good question, and it may not be possible. I normally expire based on time, not count, so assumed that you could set 0 as the count. Apparently not, at least in the Console. And looking at the API docs, the elements of `LifecyclePolicyText` aren't documented. However, using count > 1 is [one of the AWS examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/lifecycle_policy_examples.html#lifecycle_policy_example_number), and that doc is clear that one image will be retained.

Comment: thanks for the hint! yes, my policy is in line with the documentation, and AWS states in the headline that "one untagged image be kept" - cleary not the 0 I was aiming for. But now that is weird for 2 reasons: (A) in my example above, all untagged images of A are removed (so `count == 1` seems to apply to an entire repo, not each image (?!), and (B) is it too much to ask if I want a `prune` command, and "plain and simple delete all untagged images"? So weird

Comment: It is possible to upload multiple `sets` of images in single repository. But it is theoretically *weird*. ECR repo URL should be `012345678901.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/image-name` (compare it with default docker.hub URL standard: `docker.io/nginx` → `registry_url/image:version_as_tag`). It will be weird if you set image name like: `docker.io/nginx:python` and will be able download `python` image from `nginx` repository, isn't? So if you will follow rule `1 repo` == `1 image` where tags are versions of same image then `seems to apply to an entire repo` behavior will be normal

Comment: Not really.. it makes perfect sense to upload 2 distinct versions (both tagged, say v2.2.3 and v2.2.4) into one repo (the original intent of tagging). That is totally different from the concept of untagged/dangling, no?

Comment: `to upload 2 distinct versions` → that is. You have multiple versions (2.2.3, 2.2.4) of same image `A`. Let's say that you decided to store two versions: latest and previous one to be able revert last release. here is two possible solutions: 1. set `count` to `0` and all untagged versions will be removed. When you upload new 2.2.5 version you have to untag 2.2.3 manually and it will be deleted by lifecycle. 2. you may set `count` to `1` and control manually only one tag `latest` and untag all other versions. In this case `latest` and one newest previous version will be stored.

Comment: `seems to apply to an entire repo, not each image (?!), and (B)` → I just want to say if you follow rule `1 repo == 1 image (with possible multiple versions)` your expression may be refrazed to: `apply to all versions of an entire image`. And that is not weird at least for me.

Comment: `count to 0` is not possible; that's my issue. I understand your 2 choices, but it does not look like option (1) above is actually feasible..